# Accessing MediaRecorder bytes while recording in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, audio-recording, mediarecorder

I would like to access the audio bytes that is being recorded by `MediaRecorder` during the recording process so I can send them with UdpClient to a server application.

I'm able to do this with `AudioRecord` by doing the following (note the `while(true)` loop)

```
        endRecording = false;
        isRecording = true;

        audioBuffer = new Byte[1024];
        audioRecord = new AudioRecord (
            // Hardware source of recording.
            AudioSource.Mic,
            // Frequency
            11025,
            // Mono or stereo
            ChannelIn.Mono,
            // Audio encoding
            Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit,
            // Length of the audio clip.
            audioBuffer.Length
            );

        audioRecord.StartRecording ();
        while (true) {
            if (endRecording) {
                endRecording = false;
                break;
            }
            try {
                // Keep reading the buffer while there is audio input.
                int numBytes = await audioRecord.ReadAsync (audioBuffer, 0, audioBuffer.Length);

                //Send the audio data with the DataReceived event where it gets send over UdpClient in the Activity code
                byte[] encoded = audioBuffer; //TODO: encode audio data, for now just stick with regular PCM audio
                DataReceived(encoded);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.Out.WriteLine (ex.Message);
                break;
            }
        }
        audioRecord.Stop ();
        audioRecord.Release ();
        isRecording = false;
```

But I'm not sure how to get the bytes out of `MediaRecorder` so I can do something similar. Most of the examples I see only work with a file after the recording has been finished like the following example code from [here](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/working_with_audio) and [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/audio-capture.html).

I don't want to wait for a complete recording before it starts to send. I don't need `MediaRecorder` to record a file, just give me access to the bytes. But having the option to both write to a file and send the bytes would work well. Is there a way to do this, perhaps by using `ParcelFileDescriptor` or something else?

Comment: Nope, I just stuck with `AudioRecord` in the end.

Comment: Did anyone find answer to this?